# Restore Ubuntu 16.04 splash screen

Tags: boot, unity, gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit. I decided to try another desktop environment (Gnome) a week ago but I found it would be better to just keep using Unity so I switched back. The problem I encountered is it seems I can't restore my Ubuntu splash screen when starting up the PC, it shows that gray Gnome splash screen.

How can I restore it without reinstalling the entire thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the splash screen or plymouth boot screen run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

and choose number corresponding to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth` to set this as default.

Comment: You have to do the same for `text.plymouth` -> /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth